# Is there a rule that non-Jews cannot mention the name of Hashem during prayers?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, gentiles, shemos-sacred-names, noahidism

I have heard someone asking if he can mention the name of HKBH and then he said why is there such a rule that he can't... I never heard such a thing, here is his question:
"Should we not say the name at all, not even in prayer? Do we say Hashem in reference to Him because it's more respectful, and then say Abba, G-d, El-him, etc in prayer?"

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/3135) site which deals with this.

The gemara (Megilla 15a) presents the following points:

1. Aronah blessed David - "Aravna said to the king (you should find favor with Hash-m)";
2. Daryavesh blessed Daniel - "Elokecha... will save you (from the lions)"

The pesukim (in Shmuel II, 24:23 and Daniel 6:17) indicate that the speakers, a Yevusi and a Mede (I think), used Hashem's name.

Comment: But were they right to do so?